# Get larger (non-thumbnail) image for Facebook Graph Link object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get larger, non-thumbnail image for a link object? For example, given the link object https://graph.facebook.com/344600782244586, how can I get something larger than the thumbnail?

https://graph.facebook.com/344600782244586/picture does not work. It gives me the error "No node specified". Which means I can't use the type parameter.

The link object has a picture property with a value of http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAjeHBmdhzmBYB7&w=90&h=90&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com%2F2012%2F03%2Fgf.jpg%3Fw%3D150. That will give me the thumbnail. I've tried just playing with the w and h values, but then Facebook just returns a 1x1 GIF.

My current approach is to pull out the url parameter and use that, but I'm wondering if there is a FB approach I can use.

Comment: Did you find a way around this issue?

Comment: Experiencing the same problem over here... how to get bigger pictures from safe_image.php without extracting the original url?

Answer (score 3):

seems there is a new "**full_picture**" field to ask for:

```
/posts?fields=full_picture
```

note that it's still not referenced, so I don't know if it's working at 100% and seems to be great for links but not pictures.

I personally combines 2 solutions:

if link I use full_picture field

```
<img src="[full_picture]" />
```

if picture (after asking  for object_id field /posts?fields=object_id ) simply:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/[object_id]/picture" />
```

Comment: After struggling a lot, finally this worked.
It should be noted that '/post' is used, I don't know but this wasn't working with 'picture'. Strange.

Answer (score -1):

I kind of found a hack way to get the larger pic. If your image url ends in "_s.jpg", just replace the "_s" with "_b" and voila. Its a hack, that may not work tomorrow, but for now, it 
does.

See below:

[Small pic](https://fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/1012449_199647420198374_1628160607_s.jpg?w=200) vs [Big Pic](https://fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/1012449_199647420198374_1628160607_b.jpg?w=200)

Comment: Won't work for the external pictures loaded via safe_image.php

Answer (score -6):

From the graph api
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

You can specify the picture size you want with the type argument, which should be one of square (50x50), small (50 pixels wide, variable height), normal (100 pixels wide, variable height), and large (about 200 pixels wide, variable height): https://graph.facebook.com/[INSERT ID HERE]/picture?type=large.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, that doesn't seem to work for link objects. Or is there a trick I am missing?

Comment: I'd love to see the answer to this. I have the same problem.